# I'm trying to match a title effect, and can't work out how it's done? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Tags: after-effects

Im trying to match the title and information background from a how to video...

It's the light beam background from 0:05 - 0:09 and also the animated light background from 0:10-0:17

I have tried experimenting with lens flare, and have searched the net, but can't find any help on how to achieve it. I'm quite new to After Effects, and am looking to learn, but I just need pointing in the right direction on what to research to achieve the effect.

Any help you guys could give would be much appreciated

Many thanks
Ben

Comment: Looks like a basic lens flare effect to me, with after effects

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a standard preset from the Optical Flares Plugin from VideoCopilot. You have a lot of control with that plugin, shouldn't take long to replicate the effect with that.

https://www.videocopilot.net/products/opticalflares/

Answer (score 0):

Could also be the Shine plugin (made by Red Giant) through some narrow shapes.
http://www.redgiant.com/products/trapcode-shine/